# UserForm internal counter for calculations

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am currently trying to create a mechanism of checking a userform textbox value (if it is empty, ignore; if it is text, msgbox error; if it is a number then proceed) in order to calculate GPAs from three different textbox values.  There are three different boxes for someone to enter values for up to three different schools, however it's possible that maybe only one will be entered or maybe just two or maybe three.  I thought that the following would work, but it keeps triggering an error when I enter any values saying:

> "Runtime error '6': Overflow".

Does anyone have any idea how this might be workable?

```
Private Sub TextBox14_Change()
   GPASum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox18_Change()
   GPASum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox23_Change()
   GPASum
End Sub

Private Sub GPASum()

   Dim Total As Double
   Dim Count As Double
   Total = 0
   Count = 0

   If Len(TextBox14.Value) > 0 Then
      If IsNumeric(TextBox14.Value) = False Then
         MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
         TextBox14.Value = Null
      Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox14.Value): Count = Count + 1
      End If
   End If

   If Len(TextBox18.Value) > 0 Then
      If IsNumeric(TextBox18.Value) = False Then
         MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
         TextBox18.Value = Null
      Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox18.Value): Count = Count + 1
      End If 
   End If

   If Len(TextBox23.Value) > 0 Then
      If IsNumeric(TextBox23.Value) = False Then
         MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
         TextBox23.Value = Null
      Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox23.Value): Count = Count + 1
      End If
   End If

   TextBox27.Value = Total / Count
End Sub
```

Comment: All the `And`s that are meant as seperate functions; `Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox18.Value) And Count = Count + 1`, need to be either new lines or `:`.  vba does not allow this.

Comment: Also you are adding a double to an integer which will truncate any decimal.  If that is not what you want then declare total as Double.

Comment: Thank you.  I have made the edits (above) and this now appears to work great when only numbers are entered, however anytime a non number is entered I get the "Overflow" error again... Any idea on how I could keep that from happening?

Comment: You are changing the values which is triggering the sub again and again till the memory fills up.  Instead of `TextBox14.Value = Null` try `TextBox14.Value = 0`.  Do that with all and see.

Comment: It looks silly to have duplicate code just for different textboxes. I would pass in `GPASum(TextBoxControl)` and work on that textbox control.

Answer (score 0):

Best to move most of that logic to a separate Sub and call it for each textbox

Tested:

```
Private Sub GPASum()

    Dim Total As Double
    Dim count As Long, numErrs As Long
    Total = 0
    count = 0
    numErrs = 0

    DoAdd TextBox14, Total, count, numErrs
    DoAdd TextBox18, Total, count, numErrs
    DoAdd TextBox23, Total, count, numErrs

    If numErrs > 0 Then
        MsgBox numErrs & " non-numeric value(s) cleared", vbExclamation, _
                    "Numbers only please!"
    End If

    'EDIT:
    If count > 0 Then
        TextBox27.Value = Total / count
    Else
        TextBox27.Value = Null
    End If

End Sub

Sub DoAdd(tb As Object, ByRef tot As Double, numVals As Long, ByRef numErrs As Long)
    Dim v
    v = tb.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        If Not IsNumeric(v) Then
            tb.Value = Null
            numErrs = numErrs + 1
        Else
            tot = tot + CDbl(v)
            numVals = numVals + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tested this one out as well but am still getting the Overflow error on the last line of GPASum.

Comment: What are the values of `Total` and `count` when it fails ?

Comment: When it errors if you hover the pointer over the variable name in the VB editor it will show you the value.  Or enter `? Total` in the Immediate pane in the VBE and hit Enter

Comment: When I hover over the variable it says the `TextBox27.Value = " " ` and the Immediate window gave a value of 0.

Comment: Thank you. It does not seem to be doing anything now when I enter non numeric text.

Comment: Code as posted works for me.  Have you made any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to everyone for your help. I ended up using the suggestions from @ScottCraner and ended up with this working code:

```
Private Sub GPASum()
Dim Total As Double
Dim count As Double
Total = 0
count = 0

If Len(TextBox14.Value) > 0 Then
If IsNumeric(TextBox14.Value) = False Then
MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
TextBox14.Value = 0
Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox14.Value): count = count + 1
End If
Else:
End If

If Len(TextBox18.Value) > 0 Then
If IsNumeric(TextBox18.Value) = False Then
MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
TextBox18.Value = 0
Exit Sub
Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox18.Value): count = count + 1
End If
Else:
End If

If Len(TextBox23.Value) > 0 Then
If IsNumeric(TextBox23.Value) = False Then
MsgBox "Error, only numbers allowed"
TextBox23.Value = 0
Exit Sub
Else: Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox23.Value): count = count + 1
End If
Else:
End If

TextBox27.Value = Total / count
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox14_Change()
GPASum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox18_Change()
GPASum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox23_Change()
GPASum
End Sub
```